# how to get value in Highcharts dynamic-update live data

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

i want to use Highcharts dynamic-update but get value in db
get data by json
result

```
json this is { data: { categories: [ "2017-03-06 13:54:31.827", "2017-03-06 13:54:24.573", "2017-03-06 13:54:17.383" ], { name: "Press1", data: [ 251384, 251383, 251382 ] }, { name: "Press2", data: [ 621553, 621552, 621551 ]`
```

,

i have 2 series ,i need get value in json where datetime now
[image: this is view result data in highchart] and code above here [mycode](http://pastebin.com/ZB1fwQ2K)
but data not valid with datetime now !!!  please help

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts expects a timestamp so you need to convert all your date strings into that as such

```
var categories = [ "2017-03-06 13:54:31.827", "2017-03-06 13:54:24.573", "2017-03-06 13:54:17.383" ];

for (var i in categories)
{
    categories[i] = new Date(categories[i]).getTime();
}
```